# Binding checked checkboxes to array attribute in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js

I have a form with some input fields and checkboxes. The route looks like this:

```
SharedContentNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    content = @modelFor("content")
    controller.set('content', @store.createRecord('shared_content'))
    controller.set('handles', @store.find("handle"))
```

*shared_content* model has, among other attributes, a *handle_ids* array attribute which needs to be populated with ids of checked checkboxes. Template for populating checkboxes (available handles) is defined within *shared_content/new* template:

```
...
{{#each handles}}
  <div class="checkbox">
    {{input type="checkbox" id=id}}
    <label {{bind-attr for="id"}}>{{data.name}}</label>
  </div>
{{/each}}
...
```

The problem is I need to get the checked checkboxes ids and put them into handle_ids attribute  of the *shared_content* model (which is the model for this template) before the model gets saved. Is there a nice solution for this kind of binding?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this

http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/show-when-all-todos-are-complete/
http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-todo-editing-state/

this probably can help you, when a checkbox is checked you can execute a function when you check a checkbox, you can create an object on your controller/router and save the checkbox info there

Comment: this answer is pretty unhelpful. Do you know what the solution is, and if so, could you elaborate?

Comment: both links are 404 now

Answer (score 0):

It needs something like this to work :)

```
{{#view class="checkbox" tagName="span"}}
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=isSelected viewName="checkboxView"}}
     <label class="checkbox" {{bind-attr for="view.checkboxView.elementId"}}>
         {{data.name}}
      </label>
{{/view}}
```